# onClick method bringing back only one object from json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am doing a `json_encode` method on results from a table.

When I do a `var_dump` on this variable. I get three objects.

```
{"id": "5"}
{"id": "6"}
{"id": "7"}
```

So here is my process.
I have an image with an onclick method.

```
<input type='image' onclick='download(".$z.")'>
```

Here is what the button looks like in my developer tools.

```
<input type="image" src="image.jpg" onclick=download({"id":"13","itemName":"","itemDesc":"","imageURL":"","language":"English (US)","category":"Presentation","size":"1970 KB","flagDesc":"","fileType":"PPTX"})">
```

Here is the method I am using. My method doesn't pick up all my objects. It only picks up the last object. Why?

```
        function download(z)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'download.php',
            data: { image: JSON.stringify(z) },
            success:function(results){
                $('div').html(results);
            }
        });
    }
```

In my download.php file I am doing a dump of the `json_decode($_POST['image']);`

I get the same object back a number of times, but just only one object. How do I get them all?

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're JSON encoding something on the server, sending it with ajax, and in the success function you try to output that object as html without doing anything with it. Does html() support JSON objects?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to see it on the html page for now. Think of it as me debugging essentially for now.

Comment: On that download page, I get my last object five times. I just want to go through my objects and have them all display on my download page.

Comment: What does the parsed html look like for `<input type='image' onclick='download(".$z.")'>`?

Comment: Look up at my post. In that download method on the onclick is the last object. I need that to carryover all my objects.

Comment: For debuggin there's a great thing called "the console", try checking what you get there.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid json. a json string must evaluate to a SINGLE entity. an array, an object, a string, an int. You've got 3 separate objects there. To make that even remotely valid, it'd have look more like:

```
[ {"id" : 5}, {"id": 6}, {"id" : 7} ]
```

e.g. an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This self-contained example works fin for me.

```
<?php if ( empty($_POST) ) {
$z = json_encode(array(
    array('id'=>5),
    array('id'=>6),
    array('id'=>7)
));
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function download(z)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:'?',
                    data: { image: JSON.stringify(z) },
                    success:function(results){
                        $('div').html(results);
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='image' onclick='download(<?php echo $z; ?>)' />
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else if (!isset($_POST['image'])) {
    die('missing parameter');
}
else {
    $imgs = json_decode($_POST['image'], true);
    echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(var_export($imgs, true), ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'), '</pre>';
}
```

after clicking the "image" button

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
  ),
)
```

is shown in the output-div